# Extract tokens per line in TSV file

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm not an expert using bash and I don't know how to count the number of tokens per line in this TSV file:

```
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Superstar%22_Billy_Graham   {(que,9),(luchador,7),(del,7),(graham,7)}
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic    {(que,42),(weird,20),(yankovic,20),(del,17),(cancion,15),(vide,12)}
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/..._I_Lose_Myself  {(escrib,5),(que,4),(episodi,2),(los,2),(myself,2),(mencion,2),(shiv,2),(calif,2),(vez,2)}
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/...And_Out_Come_the_Wolves {(band,12),(ranc,10),(the,8),(lanz,7)}
```

It should return this numbers:

```
4 
6 
9 
4
```

I have done something similar with a `while loop`, but I would like something faster:

```
while read line;
        do
            NUMBER_TOKENS=$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d { | sed -e s/}//g| sed -e s/\)/\\n/g  | wc -l)
        done < $TOKENCOUNTS_FILE
```

Maybe a good solution can be found with `awk` or with `cat | cut`.

Hope you cal help me. Thanks in advance.

In this line:

```
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cd    {}
```

It should return:

```
0
```

And in this line:

```
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.270_Winchester    {(fusil,13),(winchest,12),(.30,9),(springfield,9),(magnum,8),(cartuch,7),(del,7),(maus,6),(remington,6),(que,5),(.300,5),(cac,4),(.270,4),(wsm,4),(98k,3),(modific,3),(nuev,3),(emple,3),(model,3),(wssm,3),(m1903,3),(kar,2),(estos,2),(civil,2),(aleman,2),(les,2),(guerr,2),(general,2),(equip,2),(especial,2),(otros,2),(asi,2),(recalibr,2),(armer,2),(6,5,2),(.308,2),(.22,2),(.223,2),(.243,2),(savag,2),(.25,2),(7mm,2),(mas,2),(cort,2),(dispar,2),(mecan,2),(este,2),(recam,2),(coleccion,2)}
```

It returns `49.5` but should return `49`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk that uses `gsub()` to count `([^)]*)`s:

```
$ awk '{print gsub(/\([^)]*\)/,"&")}' file
```

Output with `http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cd    {}` and `http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/.270_Winchester...` in the end:

```
4
6
9
4
0
49
```